# PhoneGap html5 app on Android 4.0 long press

Tags: android, html, cordova

Hi I have a an android app built with PhoneGap. So, the user interface is built as HTML5 page. It worked fine until I tested this on Android 4.0, now when I long press, android give me option to select the text in the UI and also gives me options on top to share bookmark etc. Can anyone help me turn this off?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

update your app class with:

```
public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

    super.appView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            return true;
        }
    });
}}
```

Comment: For what it's worth, make sure to `import android.view.View;` at the top of your Java file, or you'll get a compile-time crash. (I got stuck here for a bit.) Otherwise, this works great, and thanks!